# IBM Blade HS21 Processor Compatibility

Tags: ibm, central-processing-unit, bladecenter

Can anyone tell me of a resource where I can find out specifically which IBM HS21 blades support which processors.

In particular I have Intel 2X E5420 and Intel 2X E5450 which will work in some of my HS21 Blades but not others.

I need to find a reliable way to find out which CPU's I can match with which blades.

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to get Hardware compatibility information is from the Vendor's website. In your case, you need to visit IBM's website. Here are some links you might find useful -

http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/xbc/cog/Withdrawn/bc_hs21_8853/bc_hs21_8853po.html

http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/info/x86servers/serverproven/compat/us/blade/8853.html#Upgrades

Comment: Unfortunately I cant seem to get the right information from it:

8853G3G (Hardware Revision 7) - Does support my 2.5Ghz E5420
but
8853C3M (Hardware Revision 6)  - Does not support my 2.5Ghz E5420

I cant find out specifically where on those sites I can find this information, maybe I am missing the obvious.